# Laravel | How to display attributes assigned to products in category view

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have problem with relationship query. I have in my show.blade.php (category):

```
@foreach( $attributes as $attribute)
 {{ $attribute->title }}
@endforeach
```

and in CategoryController function show:

```
$attributes = Attribute::where('visible',1)
        ->orderBy('order', 'asc')
        ->with('products')
        ->get();
```

I need to display product attributes for specific categories. Solution displaying all attributes from the database. I have 3 categories, each of these categories has products that have their own attributes. Not all attributes are in all categories.

My model relationship is: **Category 1:n Product N : (pivot product_attribute) : N Attribute**

Category id is passed from the view. I also have access to a specific category. But how to display the attributes of products in this category. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have relationships defined properly in Attribute and Product models, You can use below query to get Attributes of specific category

```
$attributes = Attribute::with(['product.category'])->whereHas('product.category', function($q) use ($categoryId) {
  $q->where('id', $categoryId);
})->get();
```

Here **product** is relation name defined in **Attribute** model and **category** is relation name defined in **Product** model. **id** is primary key field in **category** table.